# How to free disk space consumed by incompletely downloaded apps?

Tags: ios-appstore, disk-space, ios

I recently tried to download a huge app (1.7 gigabytes) on an iPhone running iOS 9. The download failed several times for whatsoever reason. However, the incomplete downloads filled over 5 gigabytes of disk space. How can I clear this space again? Restarting, doing an iTunes backup - nothing solved my problem so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to eliminate the "other" space on in iPhone is to do a full restore, which wipes the device, reinstalls iOS, and then allows you to restore from backup.

Just click 'Restore' in iTunes:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Internal storage management should take care of this without user input, however.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with a cleaning application like "Checker"? Those kind of applications are used to delete useless data. If you can´t delete it with that kind of applications, try to make a backup on itunes, erase it and restore the iphone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jorge. The app you recommended is not available in my country. I tried another app however that was not able to detect the files. The iTunes seems to contain the incomplete app as well.

Comment: Try with PhoneClean on internet. There's much information about getting rid of junk files on iphone.